# Problem with makefile

Tags: python, makefile, installation, anjuta

I created a python project in IDE Anjuta, added some python files and the problem follows.

I need that would make the program after a few `.py` files lying in src copied to dir `/usr/bin`. Anjuta generates enormous configure- and makefiles. 'll Show you need to register and where that would make described above.

Thank you.

Comment: I have a program on python. This program include some .*py files. How can i make so after make&&make install these files *py copying in /usr/bin directory

Comment: What is your native language? Maybe someone here can translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also having trouble understanding your question, but it sounds like you want to run `make` and have the py files copied to a certain directory. This would look like:

```
$(shell cp *.py /usr/bin)
```

Hope this helps.

-tjw